# Compilation error String cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, string, if-statement

```
public class StrTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 10;
        Object obj =i;
        if(obj instanceof String)
        String s=(String) obj;
    }
}
```

giving me error "String cannot be resolved to a variable", however if change the program to

```
public class StrTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 10;
        Object obj =i;
        String s=null;
        if(obj instanceof String)
        s=(String) obj;
    }
}
```

this compiles fine infact if I do something like this :

```
public class StrTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 10;
        Object obj =i;
        if(obj instanceof String){
            String s=(String) obj;
        }

    }
}
```

This also works fine. I would like to know what syntactical error is there.

Comment: `if(obj instanceof String)
        String s=(String) obj;` would be totally useless code wouldn't it

Comment: @scary wombat : I agree but my only question is why the error says "String cannot be resolved to a variable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce "String cannot be resolved to a variable" error, what your code gave me was this compilation error so I will focus on it:

```
StrTest.java:7: error: variable declaration not allowed here
        String s=(String) obj;
```

---

In Java

```
if(obj instanceof String) 
    String s=(String) obj;
```

is similar to

```
if(obj instanceof String) {
    String s=(String) obj;
}
```

Scope of variable is limited to code block `{..}` in which it was *declared*.  That means we can't use `s` variable anywhere outside that block. Also main reason to have variables is to be able to use their values in different places, like `int x = readSomeData(); int y = 2*x;`. But since we are not using that variable anywhere else compiler sees it as unnecessary code (potentially created by some misconception) so it tries to prevent us from writing it by giving error.

BTW [Andy Turner pointed out in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900745/compilation-error-string-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable/48900970#comment84807851_48900970) that technically is possible to *use* `s` in same line, like

```
public static String someMethod(String a, String b){return a+b;}
...

if(obj instanceof String) 
    String s = someMethod(s = "foo", s);
// we are "using" value of s here ---^
```

but compiler is more focused on fact that

```
if(obj instanceof String) 
    String s = ...;
//we still CAN'T use "s" variable *after* that line
```

---

Problem is solved for your other cases

```
String s=null;
if(obj instanceof String)
    s=(String) obj;
```

or

```
Object obj =i;
if(obj instanceof String){
    String s=(String) obj;
}
```

because there `s`/`obj` is *declared* in `main` method so those variables are available also after `if` section, which only *assign* new value to them.

BTW you can write explicitly `{`..`}`

```
if(obj instanceof String) {
    String s=(String) obj;
}
```

and such code *will* compile, because compiler assumes you are aware of scope of `s` (you may just get *warning* about redundant variable)

Comment: "Since there is no real value in declaring `s`" there is a *very* obscure way in which you *could* use it, if it were allowed. Obscure to the point that "no real value" is effectively true, but strictly there could be some value there.

Comment: (I'm thinking of `String s = someMethodTakingStringParams(s = expensiveMethodReturningString(), s);`).

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, I didn't though about such possibility. I tried to clarify my answer a bit, but will probably need to reword it even farther to include your example (which I tried to avoid, to not overcomplicate things)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Andy and Pshemo. I was just thinking why it would happen and actually it will make sense because if I don't use braces after if it will only compile next line and the scope of that variable will be just that line. But what if I write a Lambda function after that line then How will it see.